# Allocate Algorithm/Availability Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am wondering if anyone knows of an Algorithm I could use to help me solve the following problem:

Allocate people (n) to certain events (m), m can have only one person attached to it and it must be randomized each time (Same person allowed if only one option available(n)). n has properties such as time available and day available. For n to be matched to m the time available and day available must match for both n and m. There can be multiple of n that match the times of m but it has to be the best fit so the rest of m can be allocated. The diagram below will more than likely explain it better (Sorry). n can be allocated to more than one m but should be done fairly such that one n doesnt have all of the available m's
[image]

As you can see Person A could be attached to Event A but due to the need to have them all matching (the best attempt to match) it is attached to Event B to allow Person C to be allocated to Event A and person B to Event C.

I am simply wondering if anyone knows the name of this type of problem and how I could go about solving it, I am coding the program in Java

Comment: At first glance, it seems like a version of the Knapsack problem

Comment: @AmirAfghani I'm not so sure--assuming a solution exists at all, there's no relative "value" to different solutions.

Comment: So each person can only be attached to *one* event, even if that person could be attached to two non-overlapping events?

Comment: The person can have more than one event as long as they dont overlap

Comment: Could you define "Overlap" for events?

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the the [Max Flow Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem). There are many algorithms taylor-made to solve max-flow problems, including [The Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) or its refinement, the [Edmonds-Karp Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). Once you are able to change your problem into a max-flow problem, solving it is fairly simple. But what is the max flow problem?

The problem takes in a weighted, directed graph and asks the question "What is the maximum amount of flow that can be directed from the source (a node) to the sink (another node)?". 
There are a few constraints, that make logical sense when thinking of the graph as a network of water flows.

1. The amount of flow through each edge must be less than or equal to the "capacity" (weight) of that edge for every edge in the graph. They also must be non-negative numbers.
2. The amount of flow into each node must equal the amount of flow leaving that node for ever node except the source and sink. There is no limit to the amount of flow that goes through a node.

Consider the following graph, with `s` as the source and `t` as the sink.

[image]

The solution to the max flow problem would be a total flow of 25, with the following flow amounts:

[image]

It is simple to transform your problem into a max flow problem. Assuming your inputs are:

- `N` people, plus associated information on when person `p_i` is available time and date wise.
- `M` events with a time and place.

Create a graph with the following properties:

- A super source `s`
- `N` person nodes `p_1 ... p_n`, with an edge of capacity `infinity` connecting `s` to `p_i` for all `i in 1 ... n`.
- A super sink `t`
- `M` event nodes `e_1 ... e_m`, with an edge of capacity `1` connecting `e_i` to `t` for all `i in 1 ... m`
- For every combination of a person and event `(p_i, e_j)`, an edge with capacity `infinity` connecting `p_i` to `e_j` iff `p` can validly attend event `e` (otherwise no edge connecting `p_i` and `e_j`).

Constructing a graph to these specifications has `O(1) + O(N) + O(N) + O(M) + O(M) + O(1) + O(NM) = O(NM)` runtime.

For your example the constructed graph would look like the following (with unlabeled edges having capacity infinity):

[image]

You correctly noticed that there is a Max Flow with value `4` for this example, and any max flow would return the same value. Once you can perform this transformation, you can run any max flow algorithm and solve your problem.

Comment: How would I change this to ensure that m(Events) can have only one person attached to it. As it stands Events have multiple people.

Comment: Events in fact cannot have multiple people. Notice the capacity `1` edges leaving the event nodes, thus a maximum of `1` flow can enter those nodes without violating constraint (2). Also I edited the graph creation to allow users to go to as many events as they want as per your comments on OP.

Comment: plus 10 for you dedication in you answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called AllocatePerson that has a Person and a list of Events as Attribute called lsInnerEvents (you have to define the class Person and the class of Events first, both with a list of Time and Day).

In the Constructor of AllocatePerson you feed a Person and a list of Events, the constructor will cycle thought the events and add to the internal list only the one that matches the parameter of the Person.

The main code will create an AllocatePerson for each Person (1 at the time) implementing the following logic:

if the newly create object "objAllocatePerson" has the lsInnerEvents list with size = 1 you remove the element contained in lsInnerEvents from the List of Events to Allocate and will fire a procedure called MaintainEvents(Events removedEvents) passing the event allocated (the one inside lsInnerEvents).

The function MaintainEvents will cycle through the current Array of AllocatePersons and remove from their lsInnerEvents the "removedEvents", if after that the size of lsInnerEvents is = 1, it will recursively invoke MaintainEvents() with the new removed events, and remove the new lsInnerEvents from the main List of Events to allocate.

At the end of the execution you will have all the association simply by cycling through the array of AllocatePersons, where lsInnerEvents size is 1

Answer (score 0):

An approach that you can consider is as follows:

1. Create Java Objects for **Persons** and **Events**.
2. Place all **Events** in a pool (Java Collection)
3. Have Each **Person** select an **Event** from the pool. As Each Person can only select Events on Specific Days, Create a subset of **Event**s that will be in the pool for selection from the **Person**.

Add necessary attributes to the **Events** to ensure that it can only be selected once by a **Person**